# Jpa select is fired for every insert

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am using spring data jpa.
The primary key Id column is using JPA table strategy .

Whenever I try to insert a new entity into DB , an additional select query is getting fired just before the insert.
Is there anyway to suppress this select query ? Is it because the Id is set by jpa table startegy ? Does jpa always to try to check whethe the record already exist before doing an insert ?
This is causing performances issues when the inserts are High.
Let me know if somebody has faced this issue

Comment: Table strategy is the way to go its the most portable and most flexible. There is a attribute for @TableGenerator called allocationSize, this sets the pool size of the the number of primary keys in memory so it does not need to hit the database.

Comment: the issue is not with the allocation size. We are using the default size i.e 50. The problem is a select is fired for the entity before inserting the entity .